# undefined is not an object this.props

Tags: react-native

I try to use navigation between screen  in my RN app. This is my code : 
INDEX.ANDROID.JS :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
Text,
View ,
Button
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './app/components/Todo';
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
Login: { screen: Todo },
});
export default class aap extends Component {
static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', };
render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return (
<Button onPress ={() => navigate('Todo') } title="go"/>
);
}
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('aap', () => aap);
```

here is the code of the second screen TODO.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
Text,
View ,
Button
} from 'react-native'; 
export default class Todo extends Component {
render() {
return (
 <View>
    <Text>
    Here is my text 
    </Text>
 </View>
);
```

}
  }

When running my code i get an error : undefined is not an object this.props.naviagtion. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have reference to *navigate* in wrong spot. Fix with `<Button onPress ={() => { const { navigate} = this.props.navigation; navigate('Todo') }} title="go" />`

Comment: but when  clicking on the button , i get this error : 'undefined is not an object (evaluating'this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `StackNavigator` correctly.
Like [@xght](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088034/4655003) said, you should be registering `SimpleApp` instead of aap. Also, you should be using aap as the initial route to your `StackNavigator` `SimpleApp`.
This should look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View ,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Todo from './app/components/Todo';

class aap extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { title: 'Welcome', };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button onPress ={() => navigate('Todo') } title="go"/>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: aap },
  Todo: { screen: Todo },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('aap', () => SimpleApp);
```

Comment: Shall i use the same syntax to move  from any screen( different to index.android.js) to  any other screen ?

Comment: If you are just trying to keep adding to the navigation stack, then yes. It will be similar. Just keep adding routes to SimpleApp navigator and navigate the same way you did with onPress

Comment: Cool  i add routes to SimpleApp navigator  anywhere or in the the index.android.js ?

Comment: I think it’s better declare routes in a centralized place, in your case index.android.js. StackNavigator wants you to define the routes together. If you have use case for a dynamic routing, check https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1210

Answer (score 1):

You registered the wrong component, so the navigator SimpleApp doesn't pass the navigation prop to your component.

Replace

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('aap', () => aap);` by:

`AppRegistry.registerComponent('aap', () => SimpleApp);`

And also you forgot to add your aap component in SimpleApp routes. And your `import Login from './app/components/Todo';`is wrong: Login is the name of the route in SimpleApp, and Todo is the name of the component, so you need to replace it by `import Todo...`